# Is bullet character (U+2022) safe to use?

Tags: reporting-services, fonts

In a reporting services report, I'm displaying a bullet point by using the expression :

```
=ChrW(&H2022)
```

This is in a TextBox setup to use Arial font.

Now, it seems to work fine, but how safe is it ? i.e. is it likely to work on all PCs ? (The application is a web application).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work in every Unicode enabled web browser.